# How to modify an array of values to an object with keys as property names in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-loops

I have array of values and need to convert to object as shown

```
var arr =["xx", "yy", "zz" ] 

Expected output
{
 field1: "xx", 
 field2: "yy", 
 field3: "zz" 
} 
Tried
const result = arr.reduce((obj, cur, i) => { return { ...obj, field[i]: cur }; }, {});
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can do with a simple loop,

```js
let arr =["xx", "yy", "zz" ]
let map = {}; 
arr.forEach((item, index) => map[`field${index + 1}`] = item);

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Example below:

```js
var arr = ["xx", "yy", "zz"];

const output = arr.reduce((a, b, i) => {
  a[`field${i + 1}`] = b;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. To set a key dynamically you need to wrap it in square brackets (`[]`). And since `field` is a string it needs quotes.

```js
var arr =["xx", "yy", "zz" ] 

const result = arr.reduce((obj, cur, i) => {
  return { ...obj, ['field' + (i + 1)]: cur };
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

A completely different approach could be used where you combine [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var arr = ["xx", "yy", "zz" ];

const result = Object.fromEntries(arr.map((cur, i) => [`field${i + 1}`, cur]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`var arr =["xx", "yy", "zz" ];`

`var output = {};`

`for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){`

`output["field${i + 1}"] = arr[i]`

`}`

you can do something like this but instead of this " you must use ` inside loop object assign[image]

Comment: Hi, you can use SO code snippets. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355